# How can I create a tree effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

How can I create this type of effect in Illustrator?

Comment: Greetings Andrew! Do you mind posting what you have tried?  At this time this would appear to others as if you are wanting a tutorial and this tends to be frowned upon on GD and sometimes downvoted.  If you can provide what you have tried I am also sure you will receive better answers, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like painting (via mouse or stylus) with round brush. You can try. Don't forget to double-click over brush icon to open additional params.